# `ansi-terminal` how to get cursor position in Haskell

Tags: haskell, terminal, cursor-position, ansi-escape

The [`ansi-terminal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal) library is a wonderful little library that allows you to move the cursor around and stuff (without all the extra stuff `ncurses` based stuff imposes.) The only problem is it doesn't provide a way to get the position of the cursor. Anyway, that uses or is compatible with the rest of the library, that I could do that. I know one way would be to track the cursor everywhere it goes, but I want to allow outside `putStr`s and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), the DSR terminal command should get you the position, and there are also commands to save and restore the position. I don't know why `ansi-terminal` does not support these; perhaps you should file a bug report.

UPDATE: Support for saving and restoring cursor position [has now been added](https://github.com/feuerbach/ansi-terminal/commit/375616fcb8653bf9731f3f8960757c4bd6e12d91) to `ansi-terminal`!

Comment: Even better than I expected! The library is simply incomplete! (I was afraid that you couldn't find out where it was, and that things like `ncurses` could know because it kept track.)

Comment: @PyRulez, I just filed a [ticket](https://github.com/feuerbach/ansi-terminal/issues/7).

Comment: My guess would be that Windows probably doesn't support this. (The single most important characteristic of `ansi-terminal` is portability; after all, if you only wanted ANSI escapes, you could trivially do that yourself...)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, I believe "portable" is usually understood to mean "works on everything except perhaps Windows".

Comment: @dfeuer Funny, I would have said "only works on Unix" would be *non*-portable, but hey...